# I/O exception(java.io.IOException)caught when processing request to{}->unix://localhost:80:No such file or directory -when build image frm Dockerfile

Tags: java, docker, maven, jenkins

I want to create a image for maven project  using Dockerfile in Jenkins. This is a spring boot project. I have run the Jenkins as docker container. I am using windows 10.

My dockerfile is :

```
FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY pom.xml /app/
COPY Dockerfile /app/
RUN ["mvn", "package"]


FROM tomcat:9
EXPOSE 8087
COPY /app/target/*.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
 CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]
```

And the plugin part of pom.xml is :

```
 <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.example.restcurd.RestcurdApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                          
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <repository>pomkiticat/${project.name}</repository>
                    <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                    <skipDockerInfo>true</skipDockerInfo>
                    <pullNewerImage>false</pullNewerImage>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

In Jenkins docker setting is :
[image]

I have also select the option `Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS` in docker desktop .

But I am getting the error

```
[0m[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 16:05 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-07-29T06:58:10Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin:1.4.10:build (default) on project restcurd: Could not build image: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
```

I found solution for the problem. I get some solution i.e. to set the Docker Host Uri . I have already set it and attached the image above .

How Can I solve the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13):

It happens when a process tries to write to the docker daemon socket but it lacks of permissions.

Check that `/var/run/docker.sock` is accessible for the user that tries to create the docker image. In particular, by default only root and the group has rights to write to docker.socket, so try executing `chmod o+w /var/run/docker.sock` in order to allow others to write into the docker daemon socket and then the issue should be gone.

Comment: For me it was not working because `docker.sock` was not found. As I was using that in a Docker-in-Docker image I needed to map `/var/run/docker.sock` into the container like described here: https://shisho.dev/blog/posts/docker-in-docker/#how-to-run-docker-in-docker-in-gitlab

Answer (score 1):

I faced with this error too with ubuntu 22.4 and docker desktop.
In my case the problem was in "docker context". Maven can't use these contexts and use standard (unix:///var/run/docker.sock or unix://localhost:80). But docker desktop uses your home directory by default and there is not docker engine on standard socket.
You can see your contexts by command:

```
docker context ls
```

In my case the answer is:

| NAME | DESCRIPTION | DOCKER ENDPOINT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| default * | Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration | unix:///var/run/docker.sock |
| desktop-linux | Docker Desktop | unix:///home/sergey/.docker/desktop/docker.sock |

To fix it all you need is set DOCKER_HOST to your "desktop-linux" endpoint, in my case:

```
export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///home/sergey/.docker/desktop/docker.sock
```

And "**mvn dockerfile:build**" starts working! You can put the DOCKER_HOST var in /etc/environment.

Maybe I answered on a bit other question but I believe this might help someone.
[This](https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin/issues/1584/) helped me to find the solution.

Comment: This worked wonderfully for me. How do we add to /etc/environment?

Comment: For linux:
"sudo nano /etc/environment"
In the text editor that opens, move to the end of the file and add the following line:
"export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///home/sergey/.docker/desktop/docker.sock"
(your path here)
Save and exit. 
Reload terminal or system.
To check:
"echo $DOCKER_HOST"

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Fedora

```
 export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
 service docker restart
 mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

Answer (score 0):

worked for me:

```
sudo setfacl --modify user:<user name or ID>:rw /var/run/docker.sock
```